# Drop down menu showing up at same time on hover

Tags: javascript, css, bigcommerce, stencil-compiler

Im using Bigcommerce stencil.
Both dropdown menus show up when I hover.

My target is to hover on one link only one dropdown menu will pop up.

[image]

```
<div class="nav-links">
        <div class="nav-container">
          {{#each categories}}
            <a href="{{url}}">{{name}} <i class="fas fa-sort-down    "></i></a>
            <div class="nav-content">
              {{#each children}}
              {{#if categories "==" is_active}}
               <ul class="nav-list">
                  <li><a id="dropdown-links" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a></li>
                </ul>
              {{/if}}
              {{/each}}
            </div>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>][2]][2]
```

I'm using Bigcommerce and when I display the subcategories (children) of categories and use css to make it dropdown, both subcategories or dropdown menus show up at the same time. In the picture you can see I'm hovering my mouse at CASES but it shows the dropdown menu of SKINS.

Here is the css:

```
.nav-list
{
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}

.nav-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  right: 10px;
}

.nav-container:hover .nav-list
{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Would you please describe your question in detail?

Comment: @nipulse can you please create jsfiddle  and explain bit more

Comment: Question updated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are hovering over `nav-container`, so `display: block;` will apply to any `nav-list` under that container. In this case, all `nav-list`s are under `nav-container`, so they will all display.

From your structure, it looks like you have to apply the `:hover` selector on the link itself, and apply the styles to its adjacent sibling `nav-content`. Like so:

```css
a:hover + .nav-content {
   display: block;
}
```